# Open chrome extension in html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I used this code to open chrome extension but not opened

```
 <li class="bms-item"><a href="chrome-extension://dsdsdsdsdsdsdsdjsndjsdsds/nhc.html#url=http://ipaddress/check_1/" target="_blank">bms</a></li>
```

Comment: Are sure `dsdsdsdsdsdsdsdjsndjsdsds` is your extension id?

Comment: I just add it for sample

Comment: @Haibara Ai something wrong on my code

Comment: Could you provide more details? Like where does above code appear? popup page, options page, background page or injected elements via content scripts?

Comment: I need to open chrome from by my button

Comment: If that button is on a normal web page, you can't directly link to `chrome-extension://` url. You'll have to use [externally_connectable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable) to post a message to an extension that must have a proper event listener to process that message and open the required page.

Comment: @Haibara Ai Can u pls send me some sample I will try

Answer (score 2):

Web context cannot open `chrome-extension://` or `chrome://` links due to security restrictions. The idea is that simply *opening* the page may perform some action with higher privileges than the webpage.

As mentioned by wOxxOm in comments, you should use `externally_connectable` **(assuming you control both the extension and the webpage)**. There's a [handy guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) in the documentation, but the schema is as follows:

- You declare in your extension's manifest that your domain, `https://example.com/`, can call the extension.
- From your webpage code, you check that `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` is available - that means an extension that is ready to listen is installed.
- You then call `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` with the extension ID and the request to do something (i.e. open an extension page).
- In the extension's background page, receive the message with `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` and do something, e.g. open the page with `chrome.tabs` API.

**If you control the extension, but not the website**, and you're adding the button from a content script, you should assign a handler that calls `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and, again, handle it from the background page (which can open an extension page, unlike the content script). This time though it's going to be `chrome.runtime.onMessage` event.

Alternatively, [declaring the page as web-accessible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) should help (untested).

**If you don't control the extension**, there's nothing you can do for the security reason above.

Comment: Are you sure @Xan? Why I can open `chrome-extension` urls through a test html page?

Comment: I don't know. If I try it from the web context, it opens `about:blank`. Are you testing with a local `file:///` URL? That may allow it. `web_accessible_resources` may also be involved.

Comment: yes a `file:///` url and an unpacked extension path.

Comment: Try editing a link on a web origin page, and make sure that the page is not web-accessible.